# Is possible to use a Visualforce email template whose content can be freely edit?

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, visualforce-template

I need to use a Visualforce template because I have to automatically attach a Visualforce page rendered as PDF. However, I'm not able to make a Visualforce template whose content can be freely edit before sending the email. Is it possible or should I have to choose between automating the attach of the pdf and having and editable email body?

Note that I'm not quite interested in the body content of the template, it can also be blank if needed.

Comment: There's no standard functionality for this.  You'd need to build a custom UI component to allow the user to edit the email body before sending.

Comment: @DavidCheng In that case I can't use the standard email feature anymore and should send the email through apex and be subjected to different limits, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using this Appexchange package (from Salesforce Labs). You can make a flow that pre-populates this component with a VF email template, make edits, then send the email.
You will need to make a button on your object that calls the flow.

Fairly easy and intuitive!

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G5Eu9UAF

Comment: +1 for answering an old open question, +1 because I like the component, -1 because the mail will be sent through apex, thus it’s subject to different limits wrt the standard emails with static templates.